# Disable arbitrary jenkins config step

Tags: jenkins, groovy, automation

In Jenkins, what is a good approach for temporarily disabling a build step (pre build, build, postbuild aka publisher)? We store a lot of information in these configurations, and disabling it without purging it would be very useful.

Something within the groovy script interface would be cool.  If this machinery doesn't exist, then using the groovy script interface is probably how I would develop a workaround.  It would be easy to just store the configuration to disk, but it's a lot of extra work if there is some easy disable feature.

The extended email notification plugin has an explicit disable, which makes me think this general approach is probably not viable.  Thanks.

Comment: Why not just make a copy of the job and edit the copy.

Comment: Well, I shouldn't need to need to concoct a use case for my requirements, but I have hundreds of jobs and I have to support those job's users.  Having users dial in to the incorrect job will make my day more burdensome.

Comment: First, I would have my scripts in source control and just have Jenkins run them.  Second, you could make the build parameterized and have 'flags' for each portion of the script that by default are 'on' but you can can turn off when running the Jenkins build.